How to plot two separate pairs of points and connect them using ggplot?
I would like to plot two separate pairs of points on a ggplot and then connect them by a line. I know I could create two ggplots and then combine them together, but then no line would be connecting them. How would I connect the pair of points?
Here is my example df:
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3),
                 x_at_end = c(4, 5, 6),
                 y_at_end = c(8, 10, 12),
                 x_at_start = c(20, 30, 40),
                 y_at_start = c(40, 60, 80))

I would like to plot x_at_end and y_at_end and then draw a line to the point x_at_start and y_at_start create based on the id. Is this possible in ggplot?

Does ggplot2::geom_segment give you what you want?

Building on my comment...
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3),
           x_at_end = c(4, 5, 6),
           y_at_end = c(8, 10, 12),
           x_at_start = c(20, 30, 40),
           y_at_start = c(40, 60, 80)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_segment(
    aes(
      x = x_at_start, 
      y = y_at_start, 
      xend = x_at_end, 
      yend = y_at_end, 
      colour = as.factor(id)
    )
  )

giving


or group = as.factor(id) if you don't want the segments drawn in different colours ...
